# My overflow-y:scroll works perfectly in chrome/firefox etc... BUT NOT IN IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow

Here's the css:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I have a webpage that pops up with defined dimensions for the browser window. All i want is a vertical scroll on that pop up window. Anyone know the IE fix for this?

Comment: Can you specify which IE version?

Comment: @aurevilly I'm using 1E11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've gotten this to work in IE (oh how I hate having to make things *WORK* for IE rather then them just working via standards), is to make the popup via javascript "window.open()" on my button or hyperlink onclick event and setting "scrollbars=yes" attribute and setting the div on the pop up to the same dimensions as the attributes set within the window.open() call. Here's an example:

**default.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>stackoverflow IE popup scrollbars for George user3068590</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
           height: 100%;
           overflow-x: hidden;
           overflow-y: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div><a href="#" onclick="window.open('popup.html', 'a', 'width=500, height=200, resizable=0, scrollbars=yes')">click</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>stackoverflow IE popup scrollbars for George user3068590</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 500px; height: 200px;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt rutrum
    arcu, sit amet laoreet magna vestibulum quis. Suspendisse quis leo mi. Phasellus
    posuere enim in pretium blandit. Aenean sagittis turpis in velit fermentum mattis.
    Morbi porta eros in tristique dictum. Aenean quis ultricies odio. Aliquam id metus
    orci. Phasellus eu turpis tortor. Curabitur vestibulum arcu ut dolor tempor, in
    convallis urna convallis. Phasellus ultrices ipsum id feugiat sagittis. Sed suscipit
    quam sed dictum gravida. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla odio metus, lacinia in hendrerit ut, vestibulum in
    dolor. Proin ullamcorper vitae mauris vitae convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames
    ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed in eros sed arcu volutpat blandit sit amet
    semper nisi.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce tincidunt rutrum
    arcu, sit amet laoreet magna vestibulum quis. Suspendisse quis leo mi. Phasellus
    posuere enim in pretium blandit. Aenean sagittis turpis in velit fermentum mattis.
    Morbi porta eros in tristique dictum. Aenean quis ultricies odio. Aliquam id metus
    orci. Phasellus eu turpis tortor. Curabitur vestibulum arcu ut dolor tempor, in
    convallis urna convallis. Phasellus ultrices ipsum id feugiat sagittis. Sed suscipit
    quam sed dictum gravida. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes,
    nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla odio metus, lacinia in hendrerit ut, vestibulum in
    dolor. Proin ullamcorper vitae mauris vitae convallis. Interdum et malesuada fames
    ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed in eros sed arcu volutpat blandit sit amet
    semper nisi.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Element808. This helped me to realize what was going on.